# Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string but with conditions

Tags: python

BTW, I have two days learning python but I really need to do that code.

EDIT: I want to make a function to print all the words that contain a specific consonant (only one) and any amount of vocals, but I don't know how to introduce the conditions here.

I made a list with 4 elements via the input method (I know I use a different way):

```
list = []

for x in range (4):
    words = str(input("Type a word "))
    list.append(words)

#This kinda works, but it needs to be more specific. 

matching = [s for s in list if "f" in s]
print(matching)
```

In my code, if I have words with the letter "f", I'll get a list with all the words containing any amount of "f" letters and any other consonant, but I just want one consonant "f" and vocals, not the other consonants.

Comment: Explain your problem easier. What's your condition?

Comment: I want to get words that contain only one consonant and any amount of vocals
For example, words with a "k":
KO
AKA
OK
OAK

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
words = []

for w in list:
  if 'f' in w:
    words.append(w)

print (words)
```

Iterate through words and check if the letter you want is in the word, append it to a new list and print the list.

Comment: That's exactly what my code does, but it doesn't have the conditions. 

matching = [s for s in list if "f" in s]
print(matching)

Comment: @JesusArmandoPeñaLucero You can easily write the condition with more if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and actually worked.

```
word_list = []
consonant = input("type a consonant ") 

for _ in range(4):
words = input("Type a word: ").strip()
word_list.append(words)

accepted = set(consonant+'aeiou')

matching = [word for word in word_list if all(char in accepted for char in word)]
matching = [word for word in matching if word.count(consonant) == 1] print(matching)
```